# Connect Wall Squared

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

> In this connect wall are 16 words. There are 4 groups of these words; your first job is to find these 4 groups and name them.
>
> The second part is determining what 1 thing groups those 4 categories together.
>
> Good luck!
>
> Note: The knowledge tag is mainly for one of the categories, but a few other words might require external knowledge.

```
Rapids               Cardinal             Southwest            Earthquakes


Prop                 Smart                Brain                Feathered


Rotary               Delta                Home                 Jet


Galaxy               Dynamo               Tweet                Cellular
```

*Partial solutions are welcome!*

> Hint: The final answer is a bit of a pun, especially in the "phone" category. It's obscure in the soccer teams, but very prominent in the plane/bird categories.

Comment: making @Brandon_J a nice 1234 rep please dont ruin it ;)

Comment: Thx @OmegaKrypton will screenshot ;)

Comment: Maybe time for a hint?

Comment: OK, sure @Greg .

Answer (score 4):

## Partial

Based on the knowledge tag, one group is:

> Rapids, Galaxy, Dynamo, Earthquakes - all [MLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_League_Soccer) teams, specifically in the Western Conference

From @pirate:

> Home, Smart, Rotary, Cellular - all types of phones

From @North and @Heroscape

> Cardinal, Tweet, Brain, Feathered - which refer to birds. "Birdbrain" is a common American insult, Cardinal is a family of birds... I don't see the jump from bird to birdbrain though

Leaving:

> Prop, Southwest, Delta, Jet - Something to do with planes, I believe, maybe flying. Three are airlines (Southwest, Delta, Jet). Two are types of planes (jet, prop).

So the common word is:

> wing?  birds and planes have wings, there is a position of wing(er) in soccer, and the phone wings (rings) when someone calls it?

Comment: The first sub-category is correct; the second is close.

Comment: Good job! I think rot13(Pneqvany Nveyvarf vf n orggre svg vafgrnq bs Cebc), and not sure about the last one

Comment: @pirate thanks! Didn't know about that one!

Comment: First two are correct; last two are on the right track, but a little off.

Comment: The groups aren't correct or the explanation wasn't?

Comment: I thinnk the last one is referring to "birdbrain" a common American insult

Comment: I'm not sure how all of the words imply that...

Comment: North is correct; in response to your comment earlier, you just need to switch a couple words and alter the first category a little. From there you should be able to find the common theme in the 4 groups. @Greg

Comment: @North, you are correct, however, I don't see how all of the word imply that.  Feel free to add your own answer for that one with explanations (you deserve credit too)

Comment: @Greg Ok, now the final word ;)

Comment: @Brandon_J, unfortunately, no idea.  Still a little stuck on why the 3rd and 4th groupings work

Comment: well, that was poor wording on my part. Here's an idea: State the most prominent feature common to both a bird and an airplane. OK, you got it? Now what does a phone do when someone calls it? Uh-huh, that's a bit of a pun. Now what are the outside offensive positions called in a soccer team? Got that one, too? That should give you enough info.

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

> Smart, Home, Cellular, Rotary - types of phones

Answer (score 2):

First answer ever on this forum. It took me time to find how to hide a block but I managed.

Partial.

As @North mentioned, there would be this category

> Cardinal, Tweet, Brain, Feathered - which refer to birds. "Birdbrain" is a common American insult, Cardinal is a family of birds.

Comment: Can you explain how you go from ROT13(oveq) to ROT13(oveqoenva)? I'm failing to see the jump (I don't doubt you are wrong, I just don't get it haha)

Comment: I just had a thought that these words were linked with the word ROT13(oveq). I didn't really catch your question though. Like the group of 4 words would be ROT13(oveq) because they refer to it somehow.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, I'd like to understand how the jump is made...

Comment: @Greg Heroscape's category is correct.

Comment: Actually, I noticed that 3 words could create the category ROT13(oveq) so I looked for the rest by eliminating the others and with @North's help, there is the word ROT13(oveqoenva) which contains the category and the word "Brain". I assume that is the jump and why I added "Brain" to the category