# The Ultimate Deusovi Honeypot

Tags: word, knowledge, connect-wall

Behold the **ultimate** [Deusovi Honeypot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58255/deusovi-honeypot)!

I ran across the linked thread recently, and found it rather humorous - and inspiring! I've taken it upon myself to not only create the ultimate Deusovi Honeypot, but also create a connect wall *to end all connect walls* (including [mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79068/connect-wall-squared), which was frankly too easy).

**So...**

It's fairly straightforward: the connect wall contains *64* (yes, 64) words (or terms, if you're feeling picky).

There are 16 *subcategories* (yes, subcategories) of these 64 words (or terms, if you're feeling picky). All subcategories have 4 words (or terms, if...you know) in them.

The names of these sixteen subcategories can further grouped (yes, further grouped) into 4 supercategories.

These names of these four supercategories (yes, supercategories) can be grouped into **a *SUPER-DUPER CATEGORY*, which is the final answer.**

There is a solution, but it's a long ways away. @Deusovi

Without further ado, here's the wall.

```
Center               Gravel               Splatoon             Grass


Blue Devils          Celtics              Black Hole           Fixed


Infrequent           Curse                50%                  Thorax


Glasses              Pot                  Cannons              Poison


Simula (not a typo)  Gold                 Ruby                 Red


Rainbow              Mischievous          Spinach              House


Iris                 Water                177 lbs.             Stars


Andromeda            Octopus              Curl                 Ellington


Glaucoma             Walls                Evening              Parking Lot


Mean                 Necromancer          Unique               Tar


Turrets              Midnight             Tattoo               Electricity


Waist                Arthur Wellesley     Wizard               Moats


Sparse               Unmoving             Pluto                Between


Pupil                69.2 inches          Sorcerer             Unusual


Heat                 Supernova            Dark                 Quill


Uniform              of Edinburgh         Python               Burr
```

One of the super categories was probably too hard, so here it is, along with its categories:

> Java - Duke(mascot) Oak(original name) Static(ally typed language) object-oriented

**Partial solutions welcome *if* they're significant - at least three or four subcategory attempts, please.**

And of course, it's best if the solution comes from the great one himself - but who knows, maybe *you* are the next great one?

Comment: ...So what does this have to do with me, exactly? It just seems like clickbait.

Comment: @Deusovi it took me over an hour to put together, and likely more to solve. The point (as I understood it) of the Deusovi Honeypot was to create an extremely long puzzle - hopefully also one that's good quality. I've given it my best effort, at least, regarding quality, and I believe I can vouch for its intensity and therefore length of time required to solve. I can remove the references to you if you think it's too clickbaity.

Comment: Wasn't the Deusovi honeypot meant to be a hard-looking puzzle that's not hard, but impossible?

Comment: @Zimonze shhhhh, you'll ruin it. ;) But really, I think that the point of the original honeypot was to see if one could prove it possible or impossible, and solving it if possible. Just throwing out an obviously impossible puzzle would be no fun. This one _does have a solution_ (I couldn't bring myself to do otherwise, but it's lengthy enough that it's _almost_ impossible to find, but not _quite_.

Comment: :-) Specifically, I think the point of the joke was that it was recursive/fractal somehow, so that if you go layer by layer, you get nowhere. (You could still solve it by some sort of global trick.) Now, if you could come up with a fractal connect-wall, that would be something!

Comment: @deepthought well, I think that this is the closest that I can get to a fractal connect-wall, since the 64 words lend themselves to so many possibilities, but now I really want to see if there's a way to make a "true" fractal connect wall...very engrossing...hey, maybe _that_ should be the new honeypot - coming up with a honeypot!

Comment: Seems more like clickbait to me. A well-developed clickbait, but stil clickbait lol. I can't judge though, because I made a puzzle about kidnapping the mods so what can I say. I also was not aware that deusovi-honeypot was a legitamite tag...

Comment: @North In regards to your last point - it isn't, really. I was trying to write this whole post kind of tongue-in-cheek, but that doesn't seem to be working so well haha (based on the comments from Deusovi, Zimzonze, deep_thought, and you). Again, I can make this an ordinary connect wall question if you guys think I should

Comment: You can keep it if you want (who am I to judge). But maybe you can think of like another catchy connect wall title. Because I don't think "Ultimate Connect Wall" is going to get very many views.

Comment: @North maybe I can title it "Mods kidnapped by Deusovi Honeypot if you can solve this impossible puzzle you are a genius and your IQ is 9 million". In all seriousness, if more people chime in, I'll definitely change it to something like "64-Word Connect Wall".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89036/discussion-between-brandon-j-and-north).

Comment: @Brandon_J I finally finished it! Whew!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Subcategories**

*1)*

> Supernova, black hole, Pluto, and Andromeda all have to do with ***space***.

*2)*

> Glaucoma, pupils, iris, and glasses have to do with ***eyes***

*3)*

> Midnight, stars, evening, and dark have to do with ***night***

*4)*

> Ellington, Arthur Wellesley, of Endinburgh, and Blue Devils has to do with ***duke***

*5)*

> Thorax, center, waist and between has to do with center, ***middle***.

*6)*

> Python, simula, curl and ruby are all related with computer programming language known as ***object-oriented program***

7)

> Unmoving, fixed, uniform, electricity all refer to ***static***

*8)*

> Unique, infrequent, unusual, sparse all mean uncommon, ***rare***

*9)*

> Splatoon, octopus, tattoo, and quill are all related with ***ink***

*10)*

> Pot, mischievous, rainbow, and gold are associated with ***leprechauns***

11)

> Tar, parking lot, gravel, and heat are together because gravel, tar, and heat make ***asphalt***

12)

> Burr, poison, red, and water can all relate to ***oaks***

13)

> Grass, house, Celtic, spinach because they are all ***green***

The below three are found by @QuantumTwinkie

*14)*

> Sorcerer, wizard, curse, and necromancer all relate to ***witch***.

*15)*

> Turrets, walls, cannons, and moats are all defensive barriers of a ***castle***

*16)*

> 69.2 inches, mean, 50% and 117 lbs are all ***average*** numbers

**Super Categories**

1)

> Object-oriented, duke, oak, and static all relate to the  ***JAVA*** programming  language

2)

> Space, night, ink, and asphalt are all ***black***

3)

> Average, middle, rare, and witch are all ***medium***

4)

> Castle, eye, leprechaun, and green are all ***Irish***

**Super-Duper Category**:

> Java, black, Irish, and medium are all relating to ***coffee*** @Alconja

Comment: Wait I don't understand your second comment

Comment: No Pokemon?? What??

Comment: Pikachu has left the building.....I told you this puzzle would be hard :)

Comment: Also how do you do strikethrough omiiii

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89039/discussion-between-north-and-brandon-j).

Comment: Will award bounty in 24 hrs.

Comment: 57 mins.....I just want to award it already lol.

Comment: Enjoy the bounty @North and congratulations on solving the puzzle!

Answer (score 3):

I have a few

> **Average**= 50%, mean, 177 Pounds,  69.2 inches

And

> **Parts of a castle** = Turrets,  walls,  moat,  cannons

and

> **Magical things** = Sorcerer, wizard, necromancer, curse

Comment: I was thinking of those too, but I wasn't too sure

Comment: 2 completely correct, names a little loose. 1 correct but with wrong name.

Comment: The first one might just be numbers lmao

Comment: Nope. Those are special numbers.....on average :) @North